# How to expose only some routes depending on host

Tags: vapor

I have a Vapor app that needs to do most things authenticated via HTTPS, but also needs to receive unauthenticated PUT requests via HTTP.

Can I conditionalize my route definitions based on the server's host name or authentication type? How can I capture that information from the server?

Comment: Why would you not use HTTPS for your unauthenticated route as well? HTTPS is not about authentication but about secure communication.

Comment: You're right, actually – I was conflating the HTTPS protocol with the additional authentication features available to me on the service I'm using when using that protocol.

Comment: @Nick It looks like I am the only voter on the upvoted answer. I was hoping to wait for other answers before accepting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start up the different instances of vapor using the command line argument `--hostname`, you can put this code in your `configure.swift` and then include different routes as needed per host. You will then get 404s if invalid routes are attempted on the wrong hosts.

```
if let index = env.arguments.index(of: "--hostname")
{
    if env.arguments.count > index
    {
        let hostname = env.arguments[index+1]
        if hostname == "hostA"
        {
             // load routes
        }
        else
        {
             // load other routes
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative is to use custom `Middleware`. Something like this enables the hostname being called in the request to be inspected and prohibited routes can be re-directed:

```
struct HostSpecificMiddleware:Middleware
{
    func respond( to request: Request, chainingTo next: Responder ) throws -> Future<Response>
    {
        let host = request.http.headers.filter{ (arg) in let (name, _) = arg; return name == "Host" }[0]
        if host.1 == "hostA:8080"
        {
            if request.http.url.path == "routeA"
            {
                throw Abort.redirect(to:"routeNotAllowed")
            }
        }
        return try next.respond(to: request)
    }
}
```

You can then configure the middleware into routes in `configure.swift` using:

```
let soMW = HostSpecificMiddleware()
let users = router.grouped(uriUsers).grouped(soMW)
```

The second approach gives you much more flexibility.